# How to convert struct to json Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need to create JSON like this, but my code doesn't work:

```
{
    "room": "string",
    "products": [{
        "name": "string",
        "quantity": 0
    }],
    "observations": "string",
    "date": "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss"
}
```

I need convert this struct to JSON, and my code is:

```
struct Products: JSONSerializable {
    let name: String
    let quantity: Int   
}
struct Pedido: JSONSerializable{
    let room: String
    let products: Array
    let observations: String
    let date: NSDate
}
```

this code doesn't work, return nil in log:

```
 let JSONPedido = Pedido(room: receivedString,
                         products: products,
                         observations: observationString!,
                         date: date).ToJSON()
```

Comment: Check: http://www.sthoughts.com/2016/06/30/swift-3-serializing-swift-structs-to-json/ and http://codelle.com/blog/2016/5/an-easy-way-to-convert-swift-structs-to-json/

Comment: `JSONSerializable` isn't part of Swift. If you're using a third-party library like Alamofire you should explain that in your question (use the [edit] link). I suppose that your non-working `.ToJSON()` also comes from it.

Answer (score 0):

With structs you can also create a variable that will act as a dictionary representation of the struct value. In this case it would look like this:

```
struct Pedido {
    let room: String
    let products: Array
    let observations: String
    let date: NSDate
    var pedidoJSON: [String: AnyObject] {
        return ["room" : room, "products": products, "observations": observations, "date": date]
    }
}
```

And then when you need the JSON value, you can access it like so.

```
//assuming you already have a pedido instance
let pedidoJson = pedidoInstance.pedidoJSON
```

Comment: Hey man, thank you. I cant create the pedidoJSON os struct... this args "let" declarations cannot be computed properties

Comment: Sorry computed properties have to be variables!

Comment: @pbush25 Your solution works but don't you think OP should use JSONSerializable since they're already conforming to it? Or that they shouldn't conform to it if they're not using it... :p

Comment: A struct can't conform to JSONSerializable. It's not a Swift type, and OP must've gotten the protocol from somewhere else.